# How to capture data from a column with data-validation (drop-down list) from an Excel file

Tags: python, excel, pandas, validation

I need to read an Excel file, do some compilations and export all the data to a new one.

The point is that I have 3 columns in the first file with data-validation, but when I export to the new one, the data doesn't exist.

I don't need the drop-down list in my new file, only capture the information.

The code:

```
folder_iter = Path(r"C:\my\folder\path").iterdir() 

#FOLDER LOOP
for folder in folder_iter:
    path_folder = Path(pasta)
    for folder_sec in path_folder.iterdir():
        path_folder_sec = Path(folder_sec)
        for planilha in Path(path_folder_sec).glob("*.xlsx"): 
            path_sheet = Path(path_sheet)
            sheet_citacao = pd.read_excel(path_sheet,sheet_name='CITAÇÃO ',index=False)
            sheet_penhora = pd.read_excel(path_sheet,sheet_name='PENHORA ',index=False)
            

            sheet_citacao.CDPASTA    = sheet_citacao.CDPASTA.astype(int) 
            sheet_citacao['PRAZO']   =   pd.to_datetime(sheet_citacao.PRAZO, format='%d-%m-%Y')
            sheet_citacao['PRAZO']   =   pd.to_datetime(sheet_citacao['PRAZO'])
            sheet_citacao['DTAJUIZ'] = pd.to_datetime(sheet_citacao['DTAJUIZ'])
        
        #FINAL CONCATENATION
        concat_final = pd.ExcelWriter('CITACAO_PENHORA_FULL.xlsx',engine='xlsxwriter')
        sheet_citacao.to_excel(concat_final, sheet_name='CITAÇÃO')
        sheet_penhora.to_excel(concat_final, sheet_name='PENHORA')
        
        concat_final.save()
```

This is how the columns with data-verification looks like in the first Excel spreadsheet:

[image: image of the columns from where a need to pull the data]

This is how the output data show up:

[image: image of the column of my output data Excel]